# How to test if a NuGet package works with a lower version of its dependency?

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, nuget, assembly-binding-redirect

I am using a NuGet package, in my project, that is dependent on version `1.2.3` of `x.y.z` and want to test to see if the NuGet package works with version `1.1.1` of `x.y.z`.

I have tried doing assembly binding in `App.config` of my project this way, with the `1.1.1` version placed in the same directory where the `1.2.3` was.

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="x.y.z" publicKeyToken="xxxx" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.3 newVersion="1.1.1" />
       </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

However, I still get this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'x.y.z, Version=1.2.3, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=xxxx' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

How I can test to see if the NuGet package works with a lower version of a DLL?

Answer (score 0):

NuGet is a dependency management tool. By default, it will fetch the latest version of any library when you install it into your project. In your example, your project has version 1.2.3 of x.y.z installed which means it won't find version 1.1.1 like you tried to point it too.

To test with an older version, step one needs to be uninstall the current version of the package from your project. You need go to the [Package Manager Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console) and execute the command `Uninstall-Package x.y.z` on your project.

[image: Uninstall Package]

Once you've done that, you will need to install the specific version of x.y.z that you want to test with. To do this, you need to run `Install-Package x.y.z -Version 1.1.1`. This will go out to NuGet, get the 1.1.1 version of the package and install it and now you be able to run your tests. Keep in mind that the NuGet repository needs to have version 1.1.1 otherwise this will generate an error. Refer to the projects NuGet page for the versions that are hosted and available.

[image: Install Specific Package Version]

Comment: For some reason I can't uninstall the package. The console tells me that since that it can't uninstall since the original NuGet package depends on that package.

Comment: You have to play the dependency dance. You will need to uninstall the package that depends on it first but that package could have another package that depends on that one as well. Hence the dance you have to play. Just keep trying to remove the packages one at a time and you will eventually get. Also, if you haven't done so yet, make sure packages.config is backed up or in source control. Just in case this goes horribly wrong.

Comment: I figured out the issue. The reason I couldn't load the dll was because I put in the new version in the packages folder instead of in the debug folder. Thank you for your time :)